# how to add variable src on iframe youtube

Tags: angular

*The following sample code of implemented youtube iframe by passing src variable*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-videos">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12  col-12 min-width-title-decoration m-t-b" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-1 who-we-are-image text-left min-width-title decoration-img">
                        <img src="assets/img/all/Overline_Mark.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-11 col-10 who-we-are-title min-width-title-decoration-title">
                        <span>MEDIA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3"></div>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let media of media; let i = index;">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <div class="philosophy">
                        <p>{{media.short_description}} </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <!-- <iframe src="{{media.link}}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src='{{media.link}}' frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**this cant display youtube videos due to, media.link variable cant return youtube link on iframe scr **

Answer (score 0):

You should use property binding concept.

Try this

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" [src]="media.link">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[src]="media.link"
```

to avoid escaping that angular performs for interpolating values.

Also, make sure that your link looks like

```
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`
```

because direct Youtube link like

```
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`
```

is not suitable for embedding